# Analysis of differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $\Bbb{f}$ and $\Bbb{g}$ be differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$. Suppose $\Bbb{f(0)=g(0)}$ and $\Bbb{f'(x)}$ $\le$ $\Bbb{g'(x)}$ for all x $\ge$ 0. Prove that $\Bbb{f(x)}$ $\le$ $\Bbb{g(x)}$ for all x $\ge$ 0.

What I did:

say $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$
then $f(0) = g(0)$
and $f'(x) \le g'(x)$

and $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \ge 1$

But I don't know if that's right and it seems to easy. maybe I am missing something. if anyone could help I'd appreciate it thanks!

Comment: Well, your proof is flawed in that it only considers the case $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^{2}$, but you need to prove it for all functions satisfying the given conditions

Comment: $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$ satisfies $h'(x) \geq 0$ and by the mean value theorem for $x>0$ we have $\frac{h(x) - h(0)}{x-0} = \frac{h(x)}{x} = h'(\beta) \geq 0$. Multiply through by $x$ to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Let $h=g-f$, $h'=g'-f'\geq 0$. This implies that $h$ is increasing, for $x\geq 0$, $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)\geq h(0)=0$ implies that $g(x)\geq f(x)$.

Comment: this makes sense also but how does it differ from the one below?

Answer (score 1):

By considering $h=g-f$, the question simplifies to

> Let $h$ be differentiable on $\Bbb R$.  Suppose $h(0) = 0$, $h'(x) \ge 0 \,\forall x \ge 0$.  Prove that $h(x) \ge 0 \,\forall x \ge 0$.

Fix $x\ge0$.  Since $h$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$, which is *much stronger* than the requirement for invoking the Mean Value Theorem on $[0,x]$ (continuity on $[0,x]$ and differentiability on $(0,x)$), there exists $\xi \in (0,x)$ such that $$h'(\xi)=\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}=\frac{h(x)}{x} \ge 0.$$
So $h(x) \ge 0$

Comment: this makes total sense